# Firebase.child() Fails

Tags: angularjs, firebase

For some reason it gives me the error

> Uncaught Error: Firebase.set failed:
>        First argument contains undefined in property 
>   'User Info.fcd90e70-3774-4098-8615-cedd85759757.Username'

I dont know what the reason is...

Here is registrationController.js:
NOTE: Ref is a Factory that gets my Ref for firebase..

```
app.controller('regController', ["$scope","AuthService","Ref", function($scope, AuthService, Ref){
    //////////CHECKING FOR EMPTYNESS OF A VALUE/////////
    function isEmpty(value){
      return (value == null || value.length === 0);
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $scope.createUser = function(){
        var username = $scope.usernameModel;
            var email = $scope.emailModel;
            var password = $scope.passwordModel
        if(isEmpty(username) == false && isEmpty(email)== false && isEmpty(password)==false){



            Ref.createUser({
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }, function(error, userData) {
                    if (error) {
                        switch (error.code) {
                            case 'EMAIL_TAKEN':
                                sweetAlert("Oops...", "This User is Already Created. Try Logging In", "error");
                                break;

                            case 'INVALID_EMAIL':
                                 sweetAlert("Oops...", "The Email You Entered is Invalid", "error");
                                break;

                            case 'INVALID_PASSWORD':
                                 sweetAlert("Oops...", "The Password You Entered is Invalid", "error");
                                 break;

                            default: 
                                 sweetAlert("Oops...", "Error Creating this user : " + error, "error");
                                 break;
                        }
                    }

                    else{
                        AuthService.User.email = $scope.emailModel;
                        AuthService.User.password = $scope.passwordModel;
                        AuthService.User.uid = userData.uid;
                        AuthService.User.username = $scope.usernameModel;

                       Ref.child("User Info").child(AuthService.User.uid).set({
                                Username: $scope.username,
                                Email: AuthService.User.email,
                                Password: AuthService.User.password,
                                UID: AuthService.User.uid
                            });
                               swal("Congratz!", "You are sucessfully authenticated", "success")

                    }

                })  

        }
        else{
            if(true)
                return false
            else
                return true;
        }

    }
}])
```

Comment: It looks like `$scope.username` is `undefined`. I'm not sure why it's not defined, but the code you posted certainly doesn't initialize it anywhere. Are you sure you didn't mean to use `username` or `$scope.usernameModel`?

Comment: Its in my registration.html file @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Good to know. However it is either not being invoked, or it's not setting a value for `$scope.username`, or there is some code that runs later and removes `$scope.username` again. You'll have to debug that yourself or spend time to create a minimal, complete reproduction of the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve